# Find closest date matching row index using R

Tags: r, date, indexing, find

I need to find the index for the closest date match from a data table as shown below.

```
coldate:  (data table or data frame) 

     mon_dd
1: 2018-09-04
2: 2018-09-10
3: 2018-09-17
4: 2018-09-24
5: 2018-10-01
6: 2018-10-08
7: 2018-10-15
8: 2018-10-22
9: 2018-10-29

x = as.Date("2018-09-25")
```

I use the following code but its giving me an error as shown below.

```
which.min(abs(x-coldate[,"mon_dd"]))

Error: 
Error in x - coldate[, "mon_dd"] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Can somebody help me to figure this out?

Thanks.

Comment: `which.min(abs(df$mon_dd - x))` assuming your `df$mon_dd` is of class `Date`, if not convert it first by `df$mon_dd <- as.Date(df$mon_dd)`

Comment: Thanks. It worked after I convert it to date class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-c(as.Date("2018-09-04"),
           as.Date("2018-09-10"),
           as.Date("2018-09-17"),
           as.Date("2018-09-24"),
           as.Date("2018-10-01"),
           as.Date("2018-10-08"),
           as.Date("2018-10-15"),
           as.Date("2018-10-22"),
           as.Date("2018-10-29"))

x = as.Date("2018-09-25")

which.min(abs(df-x))
   [1] 4
```

presuming your data is date format, this should give you the answer you need..